Why dhcpcd deletes routes?
I have servers on Hetzner with Ubuntu 24.04 with private network only.
Every 21 hours some routes are deleted from the table and the server becomes unreachable. After restarting from the UI everything works as expected.
I have found the logs:
# journalctl -b -1
...
May 29 06:01:19 k8s-control-plane-1 dhcpcd[739]: enp7s0: failed to renew DHCP, rebinding
May 29 06:01:19 k8s-control-plane-1 dhcpcd[739]: enp7s0: leased 10.0.0.10 for 86400 seconds
May 29 06:01:19 k8s-control-plane-1 dhcpcd[739]: enp7s0: pid 0 deleted host route to 169.254.169.254 via 10.0.0.1
May 29 06:01:19 k8s-control-plane-1 dhcpcd[739]: enp7s0: pid 0 deleted host route to 10.0.0.1
May 29 06:01:19 k8s-control-plane-1 dhcpcd[739]: enp7s0: pid 0 deleted route to 10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.1
...

Not sure what triggers dhcpcd since there are no enabled dhcpcd services:
/etc/cron.daily# systemctl | grep dhcp
/etc/cron.daily# systemctl list-timers | grep dhcp
/etc/cron.daily# ls 
apport  apt-compat  dpkg  logrotate  man-db  sysstat

Running dhcpcd manually brings expected configuration:
# dhcpcd
dhcpcd-10.0.6 starting
dev: loaded udev
DUID 00:01:00:01:2d:d0:9b:4b:86:00:00:89:c0:2b
enp7s0: IAID 00:89:c0:2b
vxlan.calico: IAID aa:0c:c0:c3
cali910aa9fb4e0: IAID ee:ee:ee:ee
cali910aa9fb4e0: IAID conflicts with one assigned to caliec31db02b64
caliec31db02b64: IAID ee:ee:ee:ee
caliec31db02b64: IAID conflicts with one assigned to cali910aa9fb4e0
vxlan.calico: soliciting an IPv6 router
cali910aa9fb4e0: soliciting an IPv6 router
enp7s0: soliciting an IPv6 router
caliec31db02b64: soliciting an IPv6 router
caliec31db02b64: soliciting a DHCP lease
cali910aa9fb4e0: soliciting a DHCP lease
enp7s0: rebinding lease of 10.0.0.10
enp7s0: leased 10.0.0.10 for 86400 seconds
enp7s0: adding host route to 10.0.0.1
enp7s0: adding route to 10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.1
enp7s0: adding host route to 169.254.169.254 via 10.0.0.1

Lease info also looks good:
# dhcpcd --dumplease --ipv4only enp7s0
reason=REBOOT
interface=enp7s0
protocol=dhcp
ip_address=10.0.0.10
subnet_cidr=32
broadcast_address=10.0.0.10
network_number=10.0.0.10
subnet_mask=255.255.255.255
classless_static_routes=10.0.0.1/32 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.0/16 10.0.0.1 169.254.169.254/32 10.0.0.1
routers=10.0.0.1
interface_mtu=1450
dhcp_lease_time=86400
dhcp_message_type=5
dhcp_server_identifier=10.0.0.1
ms_classless_static_routes=10.0.0.1/32 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.0/16 10.0.0.1 169.254.169.254/32 10.0.0.1

/etc/dhcpcd.conf has not been changed and contains the following default values:
duid
persistent
vendorclassid
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
option host_name
option rapid_commit
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private

The issue happens on 2 of 20 servers only. These servers are configures equally.
The server runs kubernates control plane with Calico CNI.
